# shortest way up in a dependency list of items of a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

Providing I have this data structure:

```
{'id': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5', 5: '6', 6: '7', 7: '8'},
'parents': {0: [],
  1: ['1'],
  2: ['1'],
  3: ['3'],
  4: ['3'],
  5: ['5', '4'],
  6: ['3', '2'],
  7: ['7', '6', '5', '2']}}
mypd=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydata)
```

Resulting in:
[image]

The table show the dependencies. every entity depends on a number of higher up entities which also depend on higher up entities. All the dependencies end up in 1 in one way or another.

I am looking for an algorithm to find the shortest path from every of the items up to 1.
For instance item 8 since depends on 2 might reach one only with two jumps.
Shortest way would be 2,1.

I am guessing that I need a recursive function that gets the highest number in the list of every parent recursively.
But I dont know how to implement this.

The problem can also be seen as the shortest way from 1 to any of the other ítems.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: You need the shortest path length or you need the shortest path itself? If its the latter, then is there any constraint on multiple shortest paths?

Comment: All the shortest paths when there are several

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure python solution for finding the shortest path with the implicit assumption that paths are unidirectional.
It first generates all possible paths and then selects the shortest. If several shortest paths exists, it returns a list with all of them.

```
parents = {
    '1' : [],
    '2' : ['1'],
    '3' : ['1'],
    '4' : ['3'],
    '5' : ['3'],
    '6' : ['5', '4'],
    '7' : ['3', '2'],
    '8' : ['7', '6', '5', '2'],   
}

def shortestPath(item):

    item = str(item) # because numbers are given as str in the example
    allPathsList = []

    def allPaths(item, path = []):
        nonlocal allPathsList
        path.append(item)

        if len(parents[item]) == 0:
            allPathsList.append(path) # apend path to list when end reached
        elif len(parents[item]) == 1:
            allPaths(parents[item][0], path) # for single parent proceed along path
        else:
            for parent in parents[item]:
                allPaths(parent, list(path)) # create bifurcations for multiple parents

    allPaths(item)

    minLength = len(parents) # amound of items should be longest possible path
    for path in allPathsList:
        minLength = min(minLength, len(path)) # look if shorter ones exist

    # retrieve all paths having minLength
    returnList = [path for path in allPathsList if len(path) == minLength]
    if len(returnList) == 1: # if a distinct shortest path exists, return only this one
        return returnList[0]
    return returnList # otherwise return list of alternatives

shortestPath(8)
> ['8', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Dijkstra has to say:

```
Link Costs, a generic path finder
l 2 1 1
l 3 1 1
l 4 3 1
l 5 3 1
l 6 5 1
l 6 4 1
l 7 3 1
l 7 2 1
l 8 7 1
l 8 6 1
l 8 5 1
l 8 2 1
 
2 -> 1 ->


3 -> 1 ->


4 -> 3 -> 1 ->


5 -> 3 -> 1 ->


6 -> 8 -> 2 -> 1 ->


7 -> 3 -> 1 ->


8 -> 2 -> 1 ->
```

C++ code for this:

```cpp
#include "cPathFinder.h"

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // intoduce ourself
    std::cout << "Link Costs, a generic path finder\n";

    // check command line
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "usage: costs <inputfilename>\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    // construct path finder
    cPathFinder finder;

    // read input
    finder.read( argv[1] );

    finder.end( 1 );

    for( int s = 2; s <= 8; s++ ) {
        finder.start( s );
        finder.path();
        std::cout << finder.pathText() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The C++ code for cPathFinder is available at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder

Ooops! I think that you intend the links to be unidirectional  So to get the result you need you would need to specify unidirectional links from higher to lower nodes.  ( cPathFinder at present only handles bidirectional links. )

The answer to your question

> I am looking for an algorithm to find the shortest path from every of the items up to 1

is the Dijsktra algoritm, applied to a graph with unidirectional links.